# update database through textbox using LINQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have a problem when trying to update the table which has only one record, I'm using LINQ to SQL and two textboxes. I retrieve records and display them in the texboxes when the page loads and I want to update the table when the user press the updateabout but it doesn't update.

```
    DataClassesDataContext ss = new DataClassesDataContext();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


     var about = (from p in ss.abouts select p).First();


      if (!Page.IsPostBack)

      {
         txtaboutname.Text = about.title;
         txtabouttext.Text = about.text;
      }

  }


  protected void updateabout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {

    var about = (from p in ss.abouts select p).First();

    about.title = txtaboutname.Text;
    about.text = txtabouttext.Text;


    ss.SubmitChanges(); 

 }
```

Comment: Where is the SubmitChanges()?

Comment: What is `ss`? Are you getting any error messages? Is `updateabout_Click` definitely executing?

Comment: @FeliceM, submitchanges(); is in the last line.

Comment: @Snixtor, ss get's data from linq to sql (DataClassesDataContext ss = new DataClassesDataContext();) and no error message, when I press the updateabout postback happens so It execute.

Answer (score 1):

```
   var query = from p in dc.Employee
           select p;

   foreach (Employee emp in query)
   {
       emp.Name = txtName.Text;
       emp.ID = txtID.Text;
   }

   dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: I got what you mean but the exception: "The type or namespace name 'Employee' could not be found" appears. * Employee = abouts

Comment: Did you drop abouts or Employees table on the Object Relational Designer?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var about = from p in ss.abouts
             select p;

foreach (abouts ab in about)
{
  ab.title = txtaboutname.Text;
  ab.text = txtabouttext.Text;
}

ss.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: I used "foreach (var ab in about)" for the for each line and it doesn't update the table. when i use "foreach (abouts ab in about)" "the type abouts could not be found" error appears in visual studio.

Comment: @farhang67, abouts is a class that you are trying to update. So, we are creating an object ab of Table abouts and assigning the value in textboxes to the title and text property of ab object.

Answer (score 0):

I found where this problem came from: I forgot set a primary key in the table abouts and I added primary key and checked again and problem solved.